# All Browsers Crashing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, browser

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my PC. Currently I am facing lot of problems with my browsers. All browsers keep crashing on my PC. I also tried different browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, and Opera). But no result, all my browsers keeps crashing.

I don't know why my browsers are crashing. Please help me to overcome this issue.

My system details:

- 2 4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous RAM,
- 1TB hard disk,
- Intel i3 Processor.

[image: image opera_crash]
[image]

Comment: 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: If it is Core i3, probably 64, but just checking.

Comment: Do the browsers give crash output?

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.  Core i3 Processor.  I added image for your reference.

Comment: I apologize but the Chrome image is much to small to be readable.

Comment: Have you tried a different webpage?

Comment: Thank @Mark Yisri.  Yes I tried different web pages.  Chrome and Chromium gives me 'Aw! snap' error.  Firefox also closes instantly.  Opera gives me page error report.  I cannot do memtest to test my ram.  I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode.  Memtest is not visible in grub menu.

Comment: Please show contents of `/boot` directory.

Comment: 1)abi-4.4.0-31-generic                  memtest86+.bin
2)abi-4.4.0-38-generic                  memtest86+.elf
3)abi-4.4.0-42-generic                  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
4)config-4.4.0-31-generic               System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
5)config-4.4.0-38-generic               System.map-4.4.0-38-generic
6)config-4.4.0-42-generic               System.map-4.4.0-42-generic
7)efi                                   vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic

Comment: 8)grub                                  vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed
9)initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic           vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
10)initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic.old-dkms  vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic.efi.signed
11)initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic           vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic
12)initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic           vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed
13)memdisk

Comment: interesting, i see memtest there..

Comment: Hi Mark! But I cannot see memtest in grub menu.  What I do to enable memtest in grub menu.

Comment: Hi! I downloaded memtest86 from this http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm website. I created bootable ISO. I ran memtest86 using the live CD, it supports UEFI (Memtest v7. 1). My memtest was passed there are no ram errors. But still I am facing same browsers crashing issue. I don't know which is causing to crash all browsers in my Ubuntu 16.04. I updated Intel video drivers. Still, I am facing browsers crashing issue. Kindly any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you try a 14.04 live image and try your browsers?

Comment: Hi Mark!  I tried my browsers using Ubuntu 14.04 live CD, its working.  I browsed 30 minutes with all browsers.  I could not find any issues.

Comment: Strange, seems like a problem with 16.04 then

Comment: Can you try 15.10 (if it's not too hard on your bandwith)